# getting null from getResourceAsStream when using Travis-CI and Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci

In my gradle project, it has a resources directory. Using the static getResourceAsStream, I access a file from that directory. This works in Eclipse or when running gradle from the command line locally. But when running in Travis-CI, it is not able to find the file.

I have tried using the "Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream" and "LenPEGUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream", but each of those either made it stop working locally, or still failed in Travis-CI.

the build.gradle with the source sets

```
sourceSets{
    main{
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'resources'
        }
    }
    test{
        java{
            srcDir 'test'
        }
        resources{
            srcDir 'testResources'
        }
    }
}
```

The java code reading the file:

```java
    private static BufferedImage lenna;
    static {
        try {
            InputStream lennaInputStream = LenPEGUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("/lenna.png");
            setLenna(ImageIO.read(lennaInputStream));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Locally this works. But in Travis-CI I get an exception:

```java
jjcard.jlenpeg.lenPEGWriterTest STANDARD_ERROR
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
        at jjcard.jlenpeg.LenPEGUtil.<clinit>(LenPEGUtil.java:96)
        at jjcard.jlenpeg.lenPEGWriterTest.setup(lenPEGWriterTest.java:23)
```

Comment: You're *running* (and not just *building*) your code on TravisCI, with Gradle? How? Post the code and the command used to do that. Also show us the exact file location and name (I suspect you have a case issue, which doesn't show up on Windows but shows up on Linux)

Comment: @JBNizet you are correct, it was a case-sensitivity issue this entire time. I have no idea how I missed that for so long.